# adding php variable to mysqli $row->something   syntax

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to retreive an attribute called points_name_1

```
$row->points_name_1
```

But in the following way

```
$i=1;
$row->points_name_.$i
```

When I do that way I get only "1" What's the correct way to write this thing ?

Comment: Do you want $i in loop , i mean 1,2 and so and so ?

Comment: Do you just want to echo a value + the number or do you want to retreive an attribute called points_name_1?

Comment: retreive an attribute called points_name_1

Comment: He wants a variable member name. And this is clearly a perfect example of lacking knowledge. Arrays are invented specifically for this purpose, to be iterated over by changing a key (number). It's also much better to fetch the mysqli result as an array rather than object, because, as seen, you don't know how to create variable member name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i=1;
$row->{"points_name_{$i}"};
```

Answer (score 2):

create a string with the correct param name:

```
$i=1;
$param_name = 'points_name_'.$i;
$row->$param_name;
```

Comment: Aleks your solution does not work, looks better then this but no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get the value of `points_name_1` member variable.  You can do something like this:

```
$i = 1;
$var = "points_name_$i";
$value = $row->$var;
```